# How to choose Android DRM plugin?

Tags: android, drm

Recently, I am researching Android DRM in the Android source.
Now, I know how to add 3rd DRM plugin library
(Please see frameworks/base/drm/libdrmframework/plugins, You can follow the example plugin passthru).

But Now I face an new problem: 
If there serval plugins,  How can I choose which DRM plugin to use from the JAVA code?
I have not found an API for it in  the ANDROID API(http://developer.android.com/reference/android/drm/package-summary.html)

Any one Know it?

Comment: OK, Now I find the Android Java API that choose which DRM plugin to use.    android.drm.DrmManagerClient:
openConvertSession(...)   // choose
closeConvertSession(...)

Comment: Sorry, before is error. Please see   android.drm.DrmInfoRequest.public DrmInfoRequest (int infoType, String mimeType),  mimeType points which plugin to use.

Comment: Thank you for asking and answering this question. If you post your answer comment as a full answer, I'll be happy to upvote it.